# TinyMCE 5 integration with Angular 7

Tags: angular, tinymce-5

I'm trying to integrate TinyMCE 5, in my Angular 7 project.
It is working fine on *stackblitz*. Here's the link: 
[TinyMCE 5 with Angular 7](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynuxzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Note that, the following warning comes up on slackblitz:

```
This domain is not registered with Tiny Cloud. Start a free trial to discover our premium cloud services and pro support.
```

I've downloaded the project from slackblitz and installed the packages. But after running the project locally this error comes up:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/themes/silver/theme.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: The docs have instructions on how to install the Angular library to work with a project. https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular#loading-tinymce-by-yourself

Comment: @Reactgular This is the procedure I've followed and faced the issue I've explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed after adding these two options:

```
this.tinymceInit = {
      base_url: '/tinymce',
      suffix: '.min',
...
}
```